Bending moment equation explanation
I want to derive the flexure equation
$$\sigma(y)=\frac{M}{I}y$$
where $\sigma$ is the stress, $I$ is the area moment of inertia and $y$ is the distance from the neutral line of the object that is exposed to bending.
But in the derivation, one of the steps is the equation
$$M=\int_A \sigma y dA\tag1$$
I don't understand what that equation represents, why is there an $y$ under the integral?
On the wiki I found the equation:
$${\displaystyle \mathbf {M} _{x}=\int _{A}\mathbf {r} \times (\sigma _{xx}\mathbf {e} _{x}+\sigma _{xy}\mathbf {e} _{y}+\sigma _{xz}\mathbf {e} _{z})\,dA\quad {\text{where}}\quad \mathbf {r} =y\,\mathbf {e} _{y}+z\,\mathbf {e} _{z}\,.}\tag2$$
but this one is even more confusing.
Can someone please give an intuitive explanation of what the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ mean?


"I don't understand what that equation represents, why is there an $y$ under the integral?" For one thing you wouldn't have units of moment- N.m.

The text really should define x, y, and z if they are trying to teach you properly.  Typically, y is vertical, x is along the beam, and z is out of the page.  If you slice the beam vertically and replace the right side by the appropriate forces and moments (i.e. draw a free body diagram of a cut beam), $\sigma dA$ represents the incremental (x) force on a little patch of material along the vertical beam cut.  You are trying to sum the MOMENT about the z axis, which points out of the page.  To turn a force into a moment, you need to multiply by a moment arm.  That is what $y$ represents, the distance from the z axis.
I am sure there are plenty of illustrations of this online, but I know for a fact that there is a good one in my "Mechanics of Materials" text by Beer and Johnston, if you can get hold of it.

Elemental beam theory
Elemental force
$$ dF=  \sigma_y dA $$
Elemental moment
$$dM= y \cdot dF $$
Integrated moment
$$M=\int \sigma_ y\cdot y\cdot dA$$
which equals EI times beam curvature as per Euler-Bernoulli.
